# How to insert a <a> tag or icon inside Vuetify internationalization?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I'm currently working on a project based on `Vuetify`. I need to insert a `<a>` tag and icon inside an internationalization text. Generally, it is easy to insert a variable as below shows,

`this.$vuetify.lang.$t('I'm {0}', varirable_name)`

but in this way, I cannot insert `<a>` tag or an icon `<v-icon>`, how could I achieve it?
Just like this,

```
`this.$vuetify.lang.$t('Here is an icon {0} and a {1}', <v-icon />, <a>link</a>)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `v-html` directive to output raw HTML. It will work for basic tags but won't work for Vuetify's v-tags (for example, `v-icon`).

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      message: this.$vuetify.lang.t('Here is an bold {0} and a {1}', "<strong>text</strong>", "<a>link</a>")
    }
  }

}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container><span v-html="message"></span ></v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

I wouldn't recommend using Vuetify tags in composite format strings. Instead, translate the text inside of the tag.

```
<v-btn class="ma-2" color="primary" dark>
    Accept  // <- translate only this
    <v-icon dark right>
        mdi-checkbox-marked-circle
    </v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is quite close to what I want; however, it seems I still cannot use `<v-icon>`. Is there any solution that I can insert a `<v-icon>` tag inside a string?

Comment: Vuetify renders `<v-icon>` tag as `<i class="v-icon notranslate fas fa-lock theme--light" aria-hidden="true"></i>`. Here `fas` declares Font Awesome icons and `fa-lock` is the icon ID. You could use that instead (change icon ID for whatever icon you need). However, I wouldn't recommend this approach because you will lose access to [v-icon API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-icon/)